# AnythingSlider with fade effect

Tags: javascript, anythingslider

I'm using the anythingSlider by Chris Coyier.

Can anyone tell how to change from slide effect to fade effect?

Regrets,
Saulo

Answer (score 3):

Well, as [the core](https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider) is at this time (v1.5.6.1), it isn't possible to transition between the two slides in a fade transition, but you can use the FX extension to fade in the next image. Try something like this:

```
$('#slider')
    .anythingSlider({
        animationTime : 0
    })
    .anythingSliderFx({
        inFx: {
            'img' : { opacity: 1, duration: 500 }
        },
        outFx: {
            'img' : { opacity: 0, duration: 0 }
        }
```

Setting "animationTIme" and the outFx time to zero will ensure the previous image isn't seen (no sliding), but the inFx (fadeIn) will be on a transparent background. I don't know if that will fullfill your needs.

Comment: [AnythingSlider version 1.8+](http://proloser.github.com/AnythingSlider) now has a built-in "fade" mode which allows you to cross-fade between panels. Try out the second slider on that demo page.